# How do you organize your graphQL queries without bloating up your classes with long strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

For context, I'm working on an API that integrates with a third-party API and has to make graphQL calls to do so.  Some of those graphQL calls get pretty complex, nesting down pretty deep to get to the information I'm actually after.

So I'm wondering how do you keep your classes organized with these long, long strings bloating up your classes?  Is there a best-practice I'm missing, an obvious solution I've overlooked?

Older style JSON APIs could have similar problems with POST bodies, but in those cases you were usually composing hashes with 'real' code that genuinely belonged in the class, even if it bulked up the class -- and often wasn't as bulky as a similar GraphQL string.  The GraphQL strings, on the other hand, are fixed, static entities, relying on variables to be provided at run-time.

I'm looking at one of my early classes, that only needed a single query, but that query is 40 lines, nearly half of the normal '100 line' budget rubocop suggests for classes.  A larger class, making more than a single query, could easily eat up it's entire line budget just on queries, and making a single class per query seems like it might be excessive.  Sure, I could shorten that class by stripping out most of the newlines, but then it's not very readable, or easily edited.

Comment: You could `# rubocop:disable` the length warning. There's no good reason to make a mess of your code to satisfy a tool that really doesn't understand what it is complaining about. You could bust out the queries into a bunch of separate classes, text files, YAML files, ... but that can just make everything harder to understand and work with.

Comment: In this case, I think Rubocop has a good point though -- I want to keep the rest of the class well under 100 lines, just not the queries.  Separate files makes a lot of sense and should actually enhance readablity too.

Comment: Or stuff all the queries into a separate module (if you want to keep them together), `rubocop:disable` in that module, and then include it in your class. I can see some advantages in keeping all the queries together. YMMV of course.